# What does the unusual expression "~~~" in R code do?

Tags: r

Like in this code, what does "~~~" (three tildes) mean?

```
plot.ts(x1, ylim=c(-10,10), main=expression(omega==6/100~~~A^2==13))
```

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?plotmath`

> x ~~ y    put extra space between x and y

Three tilde characters puts even more space.

```
plot(0, main = a * b ~ c ~~ d ~~~ e, cex.main = 3)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thankyou

do you mean: "x ~ y" is the same as "x ~~ y" or "x ~~~ y" with the purpose of adding space?

Comment: Yes tilde characters add space, several tildes add more than fewer.

Comment: The fog finally lifted thanks to you when I realized the "x ~ y" did not mean linear model like in regression lm(x ~ y).

Comment: Right. tilde denotes a formula.  `lm` interprets a formula as defining the dependent and independent variables and plot interprets a formula as plotmath.